# Is there any way to get onClickListener from View in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

For example, I've got a complex fragment layout with some visibility changes that appear very frequently, so the state of my layout that I've set in onViewCreated will change many times during the user works with app. I want to store its state in my view model in case of activity recreation (so my layout will stay in the state before recreation). I managed to fully restore my layout with exception of my listeners. Although I can just refactor my code and reassign them manually, I just want to know if there any way to store listeners as well. Here is some abstract code to show what I'm doing and trying to archive.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment {

private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreateView {
    //binding 
}

override fun onViewCreated {
    if (viewModel.isStateSaved.value == true) {
        restoreState()
    } else {
        myView1.visibility = Visibility.GONE
        //i can move listeren assignment from if else but maby there are better way to do it
        myView.setOnClickListener(listener) // some listener. Realization isnt really important
        myView2.visibility = Visibility.VISIBLE
    }
}

//abstract function to show what how my fragment layout will change during user interaction
fun onUserInteractsWithApp() {
    myView1.visibility = Visibility.VISIBLE
    myView1.isEnabled = false
}

override fun onStop() {
    //for example fun store state just copies state of id, isEnabled, visibility and so on
    //in that method i want to also get OnClickListener from a view if that possible
    viewModel.storeState(myView1)
    viewModel.storeState(myView2)
}

fun restoreState() {
    //finding view by stored id and assigning stored values
}
}
```

Comment: Your listeners most likely reference other views or members of the Fragment/Activity, so they cannot be stored in the ViewModel without leaking the Fragment/Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mr George Actually i did not understand your question completely but what i get from your title of question to get clickListner from View this is answer for that

make an object of onClickLisner and assign to your view

```
  val tempListner =object : View.OnClickListener {
     override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
         TODO("Not yet implemented")
     }
  }
  ..................
  ..................
  ..........
  myView.setOnClickListener(tempListner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an real example from my app

```
private fun setOnPageChangedAction(
        tab_viewpager: ViewPager?,
        bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    ) {
        tab_viewpager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                pageId = position
                if (position == 0) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.homeFragment);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.dashboardFragment);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.notificationsFragment);
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.profileFragment);
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

you can replace PageListener texts with ClickListener. It should show you that as an action.